# Persisting data in MVC for the duration of a users session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

Apologies in advance as I'm sure this topic has no doubt been asked before but I couldn't find any post that answers my specific query.

Bearing in mind that I'm new to MVC this is where I have got to.  I've got a project developed under VS 2010 using the MVC 3 framework.  I've got a search page which consists of 6 fields and a nested model which itself holds around 3 fields.

I can successfully post all this data back to itself and the data is successfully passed as a model and back agian so the fields keep the data which the user has supplied.

Before I move on to actually using this search criteria on another view a thought hit me.  I want to keep this search criteria, and possibly even the search results in memory for the duration of the users session.

The reasoning behind this is simply to save my users time by:

a) negating the need to keep re-inputting their search criteria regardless of how they enter or leave the search page

b) speed up the user experience by presenting the search results more quickly

The later isn't as important as the first requirement.

I've done some google searches and indeed had a look through this site on similar topics.  From what I've read using sessions (which I would typically use if developing a PHP site) is a no no.  From the reasons I've read as to why you shouldn't use sessions seem valid and I'm happy to go along with it.

But now I'm left in a place where I'm scratching my head wondering to myself what exactly is best practice to achieve this simple goal that could be applied to similar situations later down the line in the project.

I also looked at the OutputCache method and that didn't behave as I expected it to.  In a test I set the timeout for 30 seconds.  After submitting a search I clicked the link to my search page to see if the fields would auto-populate, they didn't.  But then clicking the search button the values in the cache were retrieved.  I thought I was making progress but when I tried to submit a new value the old value from the cache came back i.e. I couldn't actually change my search criteria with the cache enforced.  So I've discounted this as an avenue to explore.

The last option seems to suggest the use of cookies as the most likely candidate, but rightly or wrongly I feel this isn't the best solution.  I would have thought the MVC 3 design pattern would have an easier and recommended method of persisting values.  I'm sure there is but I've just not discovered it yet.

I have started to use JQuery and again this has been mentioned but I'm not sure this is right direction to take either.

So in summary my question really comes down to what is considered by the wider community as best practice for persisting data in my situation.  Effiency, scalability and resiliancy is paramount as I'll have a large global user base that will end up using this web app.

Thanks in advance!

Pete

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use cookies.  They're simple to use, you can persist them for as long as you want or have them expire when the users closes their browser, and it doesn't sound like you are storing anything sensitive in them.